# migrating xDB data to xConnect [upgrading sitecore 8.2 to 9.0]

Tags: xdb, upgrade, xconnect, experience-profile, migration

I am at the final step of upgrading a website from 8.2 to 9.0 i.e. migrating the analytics data from MongoDB to xConnect. I am using xDB data migration tool and following the guide provided by sitecore.

I have analytics data in MongoDB and all the connection settings and configurations are properly configured (as per the upgrade guide).

When I run the pipeline batches for migrating MongoDB data to xConnect, it runs fine. I can even see the migration operation in the verification database in SqlServer.

After the pipeline batch completes, I don't see any migrated data in the Sql Server in the corresponding database (i.e. the one which is supposed to hold analytics data). And, obviously in the Sitecore Experience Profile there is no data (a red label appears on top to indicate An error).
This is the screenshot of the log file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/atRnZ.png

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you say which SQL Server databases/tables you checked?

Comment: I was looking at the Analytics database which I deployed to the SqlServer following the migration guide. However when looking at <prefix>_Xdb.Collection.Shard1 I can see the data that is being migrated. However still the same error as shown in the screenshot persists. It's complaining about:   Sitecore.Cintel.Endpoint.Plumbing.NegotiateLanguageFilter.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after digging for a while, I found that the xConnect I was using was not talking with the upgraded site. Thus, I installed another instance of xConnect which also installs all the required certificates. Then, I went to the certificate manager and added the application pool of the upgraded site to the xConnect_client certificate. 
I hooked up this new xConnect with the upgraded site and made the necessary modifications in the config files. Now the Experience Profile is showing the data.